# Show spinner until the final page is loaded after some transition

Tags: firebase, react-native, architecture

I'm making an app with react-native and firebase. App works perfectly, but the problem is that, when it start it goes through some transition page and navigate checking state. Transitions are like below,

> LoginPage --> ProfilePage --> OnholdPage --> Home

Now the problem is that whenever I log in it shows me these page one by one. As my app has no deep state management things so I'd like not to use redux.
My question, is there any way if we can load spinner until Home is loaded from start. Any other solution is also apreciated. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know why this question is closed but I think the answer is sufficient for me. I don't know what else to add with. If anyone know please edit the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation you are doing is actually not the right way to do.

See the Use Cases:

> 1. User is logging in / maybe signing up for the first time. (If user is already having the account, he still needs to login, to go to Home screen.)

All users who login for the first time will go to the Profile/Login Page (whatever you have named it).

---

> 2. User is already logged in, and opening the app

Users need to directly go to their Home page directly.

---

> 3. User logs out or the login info is not right or some other scenario made the user log out.

Here the user will again see the Profile/Login Page.

---

After seeing all these use cases you can see that unless the user is opening for the first time / there is some issue in login details (I mean the login state is not right!) only then we need to see the Profile/Login Page.

### This observation is critical for the app design.

Please follow the proposed idea if you haven't already progressed to a point of no return.

1. Create 2 screens (Only mentioning the minimum required screens, please add if you need!).
2. First will be the Home screen. Make this look up a local db data that stores the login info (Username, Email, Bearer Token, etc.). Check for the data from firebase for this user. If the data returned is not correct, then logout the user.
3. Second is the Profile/Login Page. This will create a User or lets a user login. Navigate from this screen to the Home screen with the loading animation in this page itself. You can navigate on successful user registration / download of logged in user data. Otherwise, show the appropriate error message.

---

By default have the screen point to **Home screen** itself since this is the screen that will used all the time except when user is using for the first time / the app is in error login state.